# An optimization problem related to parabolas, yields a hard to solve derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, quadratics, conic-sections

[image]

Hello, I have came up with what I think is a unique optimization problem.
We are given the positive real parameters $k,t$. $t$ is the height of the rectangle, and $k$ is half of its width (see the picture).
Let the parabola intersect the $x$-axis at $x=p, -p$ and pass through the top vertices: $(k,t), (-k,t)$ of the rectangle. The equation of the parabola is: $$y=ax^2+c$$ $c > t > 0$, $a < 0$. We want to find $a,c$ such that the length of the parabolic curve from $-p$ to $p$ is minimized (note that $p$ is dependent on $a$ and $c$).

My work on the problem so far:
notice that $(k,t)$ is a point on the parabola. So:
$$ak^2+c=t$$
$$c=t-ak^2$$
So know we really just need to find $a$.
let us solve for $p$ ($x$ intersection):
$$ap^2+c=0$$
$$p=\sqrt{\frac{-c}{a}}=\sqrt{\frac{ak^2-t}{a}}=\sqrt{\frac{t-ak^2}{-a}}=\frac{\sqrt{t-ak^2}}{\sqrt{-a}}$$
recall that the length of a curve from $-p$ to $p$ is given by:
$$\int _{-p}^p\:\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}dx$$
By symmetry, the length of the parabola from $-p$ to $p$ will be 2*length of the parabola from $0$ to $p$.
Subsituting:
$$2\int _{x=0}^{x=p}\:\sqrt{1+\left(2ax\right)^2}dx$$
This integral is quite easy to solve with trig substitution. After solving I got that:
$$f\left(a\right)=\frac{2ap\sqrt{1+4a^2p^2}+ln\left(2ap+\sqrt{1+4a^2p^2}\right)}{2a}$$
Note that $p$ is not a constant, because it is dependant on $a$.
It seems as though we have made progress, we have managed to build a function, dependant on only one variable, that returns the length of the curve. The function works and returns a correct result (I have verefied it with a couple of examples) but the derivative is very long and i doubt that it is solvable. I am quite stuck here with my current knowledge. But I am positive because when you graph the function on desmos there is indeed one local minimum for $a < 0$.

An easier variant is trying to minimize the area blocked by the parabola and the $x$ axis. It was much easier to solve...

Comment: If you have reason to believe that there is only one local minimum in the range of values of $a$ (which I would believe even without the Desmos graph) then there are ways to find that minimum numerically. That may be your best recourse.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to get an expression with $t$ and $k$?

Comment: Not with the methods I had in mind, for any kind of expression short of an encoding of a numeric algorithm. There is a minimum as a function of those two values but I would expect to just run the algorithm every time you have a new value of $k$ or $t$.

Comment: So you want to compute $\frac{d}{da} \left( 2\int _{x=0}^{x=p}\:\sqrt{1+\left(2ax\right)^2}dx \right)$. Have you tried interchanging the differential and integral operators? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: @cvanaret I don't see the point of doing that: the result will be obviously the same.

Comment: the derivative is not that ugly in the sense it doesn't have weird functions involved. If the solution doesn't show up in the derivative it must be on the border cases (don't ask me which are they). For me the only solution is to solve the derivative or to let it expression in evidence.